# Ruby on rails Ajax call showing 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am making and ajax call to hit the controller but it is showing the 404 error:

**My controller method is like:**

```
def get_user_time
    if(params[:user])
        @user_time_checks = UserTimeCheck.where(:user_id => params[:user])
    end
end
```

**And my route for this is like:**

```
post "user_time_checks/get_user_time"
```

**And my ajax script is like:**

```
 function get_user_time(id) {
     var user_id = id;   
     if(user_id != ''){       
        $.ajax({
          url:"get_user_time?user="+user_id,
          type:"POST",
          success: function(time){
            console.log(time);
          },error: function(xhr,response){
            console.log("Error code is "+xhr.status+" and the error is "+response);
          }
        });
      }
  }
```

Comment: Making a `POST` request to `get` some information is not a good idea. You should do that with a `GET` request.

Comment: what is the name of the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route should be:

```
post "user_time_checks/get_user_time" => "user_time_checks#get_user_time"
```

Also, since the purpose of the request is to `get` some data, you should make it a `GET` request instead. So:

```
function get_user_time(id) {
    var user_id = id;
    if(user_id != ''){
        $.get("get_user_time",
                    {user: user_id})
        .success(function(time) {
            console.log(time);
        })
        .error(function(xhr,response){
            console.log("Error code is "+xhr.status+" and the error is "+response);
        });
    }
}
```

Lastly, maybe you should tell the controller to be able to repond_to json:

```
def get_user_time
    if(params[:user])
        @user_time_checks = UserTimeCheck.where(:user_id => params[:user])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # The .html response
            format.json { render :json => @user_time_checks }
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: i think it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"user_time_checks/get_user_time",
  type:"POST",
  data: {
    user: user_id 
  },  
  success: function(time){
    console.log(time);
  },error: function(xhr,response){
    console.log("Error code is "+xhr.status+" and the error is "+response);
  }
});
```

Also make sure you really need to do POST method and that rails route does not require specific paramater like :user_id. Basically check the output from

```
rake routes | grep get_user_time
```

Comment: what's the output from: rake routes | grep get_user_time